# DevExpress. Как организовать навигацию с использованием navBarControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

**Используется**
Visual Studio 2015
Devexpress 17.1.5

В левой части предполагается разместить "navBarControl" для навигации по панелям, которые должны отображаться правой части программы.

У меня аналог находится по ссылке 
c:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress Demos 17.1\Components\WinForms\DevExpress.MailClient.Win\CS\DevExpress.MailClient.Win.sln

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать чтобы при перемещении по элементам navBarControl (navBarItem) в правой части менялись панели?
Аналог см. скрин

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Демо от DevExpress приходят с исходниками. Почему бы в них не посмотреть?

Comment: @default locale не понимаю... В качестве Демо скачал файл `*.exe`. После установки максимум, что нашёл это файлы, которые находятся в папке путь к которой указан в вопросе. Не могли бы вы подсказать где, что смотреть?

Comment: Так в этом пути `DevExpress.MailClient.Win.sln` — это решение Visual Studio. Открываете его и читаете код.